# Haskell hGetContents error

Tags: haskell

Is the following error due to lazy evaluation?

```
epubParsing :: FilePath -> IO [String]
epubParsing f = do
  h <- openFile f ReadMode
  hSetEncoding h utf8
  content <- hGetContents h
  hClose h
  return . fromJust $ scrapeStringLike content paragraphS
```

I get an error: `hGetContents: illegal operation (delayed read on closed handle)`
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `hGetContents` puts the handle into a special "semi-closed" state. You cannot perform *any* explicit operations on it after that. In particular, you don't manually close it; it automatically gets closed in the background when you read to the end of the string. You can just remove that `hClose` and it will work.

This is one of the pitfalls of lazy I/O, and one of the reasons people advise to avoid it; it makes the timing of your I/O operations kind of unpredictable.